# Creating products dynamically in Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

We have a hybris set up without any  product data,Products are stored in MDM and displayed on front-end using another system(Java app).The request is sent to hybris when the user clicks checkout on the upstream system to create products in Hybris .
Is there an OOTB API in hybris which allows us to create the products with all mandatory fields dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You have different options to import new products within Hybris :

- Use OCC, and update the existing ProductController to have a new API method to add a new product
- Use the ant 'importimpex' target (Hybris V6)
- Use the hot folder (CSV to Impex)
- Use Hybris Data-Hub

Are you using Hybris to place the orders only ? Why are your products not already synchronized with Hybris ?

Comment: yes,we are using Hybris for placing Orders only ,we do not want to store any products in Hybris ,they will be stored in MDM system only .

Comment: Then the best solution to me would be to have an ESB (Datahub or other) between two systems with real-time synchronization.

Comment: you are always going to need some product info in hybris. OCC is not designed for this. Typically, hybris is used for the entire solution and relies on data being present.

Comment: Importing impex, stores the product and its details in Hybris in either case of hot folder or through hac. In case of real-time synchronization, we might experience latency on the storefront.

Answer (score 0):

"we do not want to store any products in Hybris " - You can probably fetch product detail information from MDM, on Demand, either by lazy loading or by the hybris server acting as proxy to the MDM server. You will still need to maintain atleast a few product attributes in Hybris to be able to add a product to a cart/order, like product id  or name.